# Ubuntu 14.04 -- The system network services are not compatible with this version

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I have read all related questions but none of those answers worked for me.
So the problem is that on my ubuntu 14.04, there isn't network connection and no network icon either. I have used ubuntu over 6 months now and this is first time when there is network problems. I have tested all kind of `network-manager` `start`, `stop`, `restart`, I have downloaded `wicd-1.7.0` (for someone wicd made the trick) and pretty much everything what the answers are mentioned for those related questions.

The newest solution I found is to download three packages `libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200` I downloaded them, manually. Then I go to the new folder where those packages located and run `sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb` and then reboot the system and after that I saw following pop-up message:
[image]

When I saw that message after reboot, I was sure that the solution solved my issue, but it didn't. After I click "Run" next pop-up message popped and crushed my soul instantly: [image]

And once again I have no idea how I could make this work. Please let me know if I can provide more information or something. Thank you!

Comment: WICD has no tray icon.

Comment: Please don't download software, please use apt-get instead: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200`

Comment: @mchid no difference. I'm still stuck. The problem is the libnl-*.deb but even if I change those 3-200 to the /var/cache/apt/archives and install them there. Network doesn't work. Weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

This forced `network-manager` to upgrade itself.

Now networking is running

Comment: Thank you Shawn.  This doesn't fix'd my problem instantly but this pushed me to the correct direction. And after few hours package downloading and installation I finally got the correct network version and then I started modify USB setting to get network connection. Anyway, at the end of the day. My network finally works again on my Ubuntu machine!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago when I allowed a routine upgrade. After the reboot I could get no internet connection.

When I checked the Error Report it was trying to send, I found out that the Network Manager had crashed (not compatible with this version).

1) First I used the following command to find out what the latest installs had been:

```
tail -n25 /var/log/apt/history.log
```

The install had included:

- libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

which I determined were related to the Network Manager

2) With further searching I found the page (see link below) that told me I could copy the previous version files into the apt-get archives and install them:

2.1) moved out the files (above) from **/var/cache/apt/archives**

2.2) Downloaded and copied into **/var/cache/apt/archives**:

- libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
- libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
- libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

2.3) Then install each from that directory with:

```
dpkg -i libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
```

2.4) Restart Ubuntu and voila! All good again. I suspect that you didn't put the files in the correct location.

[This is the link to the article mentioned above that I found helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet). Note that it talks about 'proposed repository' but this was not the case for me.

I also found this post about [how to lock the version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) of the libnl apps (note that I locked everything that had libnl in the app name, so that was a total of 19 files)

Comment: a couple of other posts have the same-ish solution:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/771627/14-04-network-manager-stopped-working/771841#771841 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/772838/wifi-stopped-working-after-updates-on-5-13-16-xubuntu-14-04-4-lts

Comment: Thank you for your advise. In the /var/cache/apt/archives I have at the moment Partials (empty folder) | lock | libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb | libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb | libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb   . And I installed each from that directory and after that I reboot the system but no difference. Still the same. I'm reading those articles which you provided but no luck so far. Should I locate those libnls in the Partials folder or should it be empty ?

Comment: I will check out those questions URLs

Comment: @lan F. Hood none of those worked.